# Nothing was returned from render:React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm Looking to **Cache Images** through **Image.prefetch()** from my JSON API but it is throwing an error **"Invariant Violation: StaticRender(): Nothing was returned from render"** in Android Emulator though I actually returned it. *(I'm Using **react-native** command, not create-react-native-app or expo)*

> **Component:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, Image, Button, Text, View, ListView, StyleSheet} from 
'react-native';

export default class Shayari extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        const imgApi = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.state = {
            userDataSource: imgApi,
        };
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchShayari();
    }

    fetchShayari(){
        fetch('http://myapiurl.com')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({
                    userDataSource: this.state.userDataSource.cloneWithRows(response)
                });
        });
    }

    renderRow(shayariImg, sectionId, rowId, highlightRow) {

        let urlOfImages = [shayariImg.url];

        let preFetchTasks = []; 

        urlOfImages.forEach((p) => {
            preFetchTasks.push(Image.prefetch(p));
        });

        Promise.all(preFetchTasks).then((results) => {
            let downloadedAll = true;
            results.forEach((result) => {
                if(!result) {
                    //error occurred downloading a pic
                    downloadedAll = false;
                }
            })

            if(downloadedAll) {

                return(
                   <View>
                        <Image source={urlOfImages} />
                    </View>
                );
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <ListView 
                dataSource={this.state.userDataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
            />
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('mehfileishq', () => Shayari);
```

Everything is running fine if I do not use to cache images.

Answer (score 0):

Render method needs to something to render or null. 
In this scenario if(!downloadedAll), then we don't return anything.

Add else condition to downloadedAll and return something from there.In this way we are always returning something for render method.

> ```
>        if(downloadedAll) {
>
>             return(
>                <View>
>                     <Image source={urlOfImages} />
>                 </View>
>             );
>         }
>
>         else {
>             return(
>                <View>
>                     <Text> Fetching image.... </Text>
>                 </View>
>             );
>         }
> ```